# How to search for triggers in a schema in DB2 9.7?

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have a list of tables in a schema in IBM DB2 9.7. Some of them have triggers and others do not. I am creating a stored procedure that goes through all tables in SYSCAT.TABLES, but how do I check with sql syntax if that table has a trigger with a specific name? (or any trigger)

Answer (score 14):

You can use the [`SYSCAT.TRIGGERS`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001066.html) catalog view.

```
SELECT *
FROM SYSCAT.TRIGGERS
WHERE TABNAME    = @table_name
  AND TABCREATOR = @table_schema
  AND TRIGNAME   = @trigger_name
  AND TRIGSCHEMA = @trigger_schema
```

The predicates given are just examples of columns you might search by, you can obviously pick and choose based on your needs.